# Excel stacked column chart with unconventional data set

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'd like to create a stacked column chart based on the following set of data:

Region    Segment    Value

EMEA      Premier    20

EMEA      Standard   10

Americas  Premier    30

Americas  Standard   40

The Region should be along the X-axis, with the Segment representing sections on the stacked column (series?).

Is that possible? It seems that my table isn't setup the traditional way wherein each account segment would be a column header in my table.

Thanks!

Comment: You can make a second table that links to the original cells, but is arranged in a way that accommodates the chart you want. It may take five minutes (or less) to make this table, but it will save you lots of time trying to get a chart to work with the wrong data layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to create a PivotChart. Just add the three column headers (i.e. "Location", "Type" and "Value"), select your data and click "Insert" -> "PivotChart". Click okay and drag the column header "Value" to the values area. Change the diagram type to stacked columns.

Depending on how your diagram should finally look like, you might want to try dragging "Type" to the legend and "Location" to the axis - or the other way round.

The final result could look like this:
[image: diagram based on the sample data]

For more information about PivotCharts, check this page: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/create-a-pivotchart-HA102919712.aspx